# Sumar los divisores pares y restar los impares de un numero

Tags: java

El enunciado es: Dado un número, obtener todos sus divisores. Obtener la suma de sus divisores pares y la resta de los divisores impares.
Solo pude lograr mostrar los divisores pero la suma y resta no me salieron.

```
public static String obtenerDivisores(int n){
        String cadena="";int suma=0;int resta=0;
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if (n%i==0)
                System.out.println(i);
            if (n%2==0)
                suma+=n;
            if (n%2!=0)
                resta-=n;
        }
        cadena = "\nSuma de los divisores pares: "+suma+"\nResta de los divisores impares: "+resta;
        return cadena;
    }
```

Comment: Resta de los divisores impares ??

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código? Cuál es el valor de entrada y de salida?

Comment: Osea, de un numero n, debo hallar sus divisores y de esos divisores, debo sumar los divisores que sean pares y restar los divisores que sean impares

Comment: Restas los impares del número N ???

Comment: No, restar los divisores impares del numero N

Comment: Por ejemplo, N = 18, sus divisores son 1,2,3,6,9,18. De esos divisores, los pares son 2,6,18; por lo tanto, tendria que sumarlos. Y los impares serian 1,3,9 los cuales se restarian.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta debajo, y he probado además con 18, todo ok.

Answer (score 0):

Aún no comprendo del todo si sumas pares con pares, 
y restas impares con impares, pero te dejo lo que he logrado corregir.

Primero, Tu primera misión es encontrar los divisores de X numero, 
en este ejemplo usaremos el 10, los divisores son: 1, 2, 5 y 10.

Suma de los pares: `12 (0+2+10)`
Resta de los impares: `-6 (0-1-5)`;

Entonces lo primero que debes hacer, es `n%i==0` para saber si X número es divisor de N.

Segundo, para encontrar los pares, quienes hayan pasado el primer IF, 
deben someterse a `i%2==0`, con esto sabemos que ese divisor de N, es par.

Del mismo modo, usamos `i%2!=0` para saber cuales de ellos son impares.

Finalmente, hacemos las sumas o restas necesarias para el resultado final en la cadena.

[--> Prueba de que el código funciona correctamente.](https://i.gyazo.com/a079bf9f49c7bb1de823b4d1b9e0e4b4.png)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 10;
    String cadena = "";
    int suma = 0;
    int resta = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) { //Obtencion de divisores
        System.out.println(i + " es divisor de " + n);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          System.out.println(i + " es divisor par");
          suma = suma + i;
        }
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
          System.out.println(i + " es divisor impar");
          resta = resta - i;
        }
      }
    }

    cadena = "\nSuma de los divisores pares: " + suma + "\nResta de los divisores impares: " + resta;
    System.out.println(cadena);
  }
}
```